# What happens when an answer which is not correct is accepted as an answer

Tags: discussion

Take a look at this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/669/workflow-field-update-action-update-field-value-with-another-field-value)

The accepted answer is probably not the right answer to the question (probably not the wrong answer) as Jon corrected on the comments.

What should one do when we for sure know that the accepted answer is a wrong answer?

- Downvote the question? (It could be a excellent question. )
- Downvote the answer?
- Or just upvote the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

Interesting point, My answer was correct as far as I interpreted the question at the time, however Ashok has edited the question to make it detailed (Picklist -> Picklist) and my answer definitely doesn't match now.

My first thought is I (or someone else) should edit my answer to highlight and explain the fact that the answer is a solution but to a similar question (Thus leaving it in place for people who may actually need that answer)

If there is a better answer I think it should be upvoted.

I will edit my answer now (Thanks for pointing it out!)

Comment: Oh!! it never occurred to me anand would have edited to refine the question. I would think it would be good practice for the user to place in the question saying EDIT or UPDATE and have the refined question. This could be another question on meta on how to deal with this.